# Cannot update Database C# in loop

Tags: c#, database, loops

I have a Visual C# application on Visual Studio 2010. On a form I have 2 listBoxes. The first one contains IDs and the second one numbers, all of which are saved on a database I've created. I also have a button, and I want when the button is clicked, to update one of the columns on my database for every single one ID that appears on the first listBox and to save all those IDs with the rest of the columns on another Table of my Database.

I have succeeded on the first part (updating one of the columns for every ID that appears on the listBox) but I cannot make the second part work. Someone told me that I have to wait between making queries,but wouldn't that make my application slow? Also, I have no idea how to do that.

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is the loop in the loop I use.

```
   if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            string kat1 = "Μοριοδοτηθείσα";
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Table2 SET kat_aitisis=@kat WHERE aitisi_ID=@id";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kat", kat1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table2 WHERE aitisi_ID=@id";

                        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {

                                 cmd1.CommandText = "Insert INTO Table3 (aitisi_ID,imerominia_aitisis,Epwnimo,Onoma,ADT,Poli,TK,Address,Telephone,email,username,password,IEK,Eidikotita,oikogen_kat,erg_gon,erg_spoy,eisodima_gon,eisodima_spoy,moria) values (dr[0],dr[1],dr[2],dr[3],dr[4],dr[5],dr[6],dr[7],dr[8],dr[9],dr[10],dr[11],dr[12],dr[13],dr[14],dr[15],dr[16],dr[17],dr[18],dr[19])";
                                 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                 cmd.Clone();


                            }
                        }
                 cn.Close();
            }


            MessageBox.Show("blahblah.");

        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have some problems in your code:

First:

```
 cmd1.CommandText = "Insert INTO Table3 (aitisi_ID,imerominia_aitisis,Epwnimo,Onoma,ADT,Poli,TK,Address,Telephone,email,username,password,IEK,Eidikotita,oikogen_kat,erg_gon,erg_spoy,eisodima_gon,eisodima_spoy,moria) values (dr[0],dr[1],dr[2],dr[3],dr[4],dr[5],dr[6],dr[7],dr[8],dr[9],dr[10],dr[11],dr[12],dr[13],dr[14],dr[15],dr[16],dr[17],dr[18],dr[19])";
```

is not inserting values of datareader to commandtext.

Second: If i where you, i would create command text in loop with concatenation of your command texts and then pass it to sql server with single request. It will be faster.

```
                    var commandText = string.Empty;
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {

                            commandText += string.Format("Insert INTO Table3 (aitisi_ID,imerominia_aitisis,Epwnimo,Onoma,ADT,Poli,TK,Address,Telephone,email,username,password,IEK,Eidikotita,oikogen_kat,erg_gon,erg_spoy,eisodima_gon,eisodima_spoy,moria) values ({0}, {1},...{19}) Go", dr[0], dr[1],...dr[19]);
                        }
                         cmd1.CommandText = commandText;
                    }
 ...
 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I got another error,that the IDENTITY_INSERT was off, so I added another query like cmd3.CommandText= "Set IDENTITY_INSERT Table3 ON"; and then I executed it. Is that okay or is it wrong? It works now though

Comment: It seems that your table had restriction on inserting of rows with defined aitisi_ID. So your command "Set IDENTITY_INSERT Table3 ON" remove this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

While a SqlDataReader is open the connection used by that instance cannot be reused for other data access commands. In your inner loop the connection is busy serving the DataReader and so it cannot execute the command.

To fix your issue you should change your connection string to add the string

```
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

[See MSDN on Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx)

and [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012) for an example of how to Enable a MARS connection

**EDIT**

```
if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table2 SET kat_aitisis=@kat WHERE aitisi_ID=@id";, cn);
    string kat1 = "Μοριοδοτηθείσα";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kat", kat1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Table2 WHERE aitisi_ID=@id", cn);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO .......",cn);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(.....);
    ... add the remainung cmd2.Parameters...... 

    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
         cn.Open();
         cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
         cmd1.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
         while (dr.Read())
         {
             ..set the cmd2 parameters values ...
             cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         MessageBox.Show("blahblah.");
    }
```

Comment: I added it, but it shows an error on  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

the error is "Incorrect syntax near '0'"

Comment: You are calling that code in a loop, after the first loop the command text is from the select . Move the update text inside the loop

Comment: which loop are you referring to? the for one or the while one?

Comment: See the update. I find this reusing of the SqlCommand very confusing. I suggest to use a different SqlCommand for each operation (of course without recreating the command at every loop)

Comment: And by the way, this could be really improved if you pass all this stuff to a stored procedure without going back and forth to the database  extracting data and inserting them in another table

Answer (score 0):

This code is written very badly and will hit the performance a lot. becaue You are connecting to database in loop and doing DML operation with many iterations. Here I would suggest

1. crate a store procedure
2. collect all information from front end into XML and pass that XML  to the SP.
3. In this SP Parse the data into a temp variable/table
4. use bulk update and insert on the basis of joins